# how to display only the category which is not applied?

Tags: php, laravel

I have categories table and I want to display only the categories which are not available in the business_category table **OR** the business_category->approved is 2.

My code for that:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <select multiple name="categories[]" id="categories" class="form-control @error('categories') is-invalid @enderror" autofocus required>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            @foreach($business_categories as $business_category)
               @if(($business_category->approved==2) || ($business_category->category_id != $category->id))
                   <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
               @endif
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

My Code in Controller:

```
$business_categories = BusinessCategories::join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'category_id')
    ->where('business_id', $id)
    ->select('categories.name as name', 'approved', 'category_id')
    ->get();

$categories = Categories::where('parent_id', '0')->select('id', 'name')->get();

return view('admin.businesses.edit', with([
    'business_categories' => $business_categories,
    'categories'          => $categories,
]));
```

But this code displays the categories which is applied or not applied multiple times.

Comment: Please can you show your controller code for this

Comment: I have added my controller's code.

Comment: Are `$business_categories` or `$categories` getting used elsewhere on the page?

Comment: @RossWilson No. It is using for this only.

Comment: Do you have a `belongsToMany` relationship set up in your `Category` model for `Business`?

Comment: No. I haven't setup that.

Comment: Ah ok, setting that up would make like a whole lot easier.

Comment: can we see your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a `hasMany` businessCategories relationship on `Categories` model:

```
public function businessCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BusinessCategories::class);
}
```

Your query

```
Categories::orWhereDoesntHave('businessCategories')
    ->orWhereHas('businessCategories', function($query) {
        $query->where('approved', 2);
    })->get();
```

You can find more eloquent relationship query information [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)